# PHP: Trying to find a common matching text inside two separate string arrays. Main Idea: Making usergroups for a forum

Tags: php, string, loops, find, match

The short description for this is that I have created my own forum. Everything works fantastic and I am quite impressed with it myself, being that I have been only studying PHP for 6 months. However, I am trying to make user groups function properly. Right now, I can assign one usergroup to a forum category and it all works fantastic. But again, I could only add one group to a forum. If I try and add more groups, this is where I have the trouble with my code.

First off, let me give you the working code I am using:

```
function checkgroupstat($group, $user) {
$findme = $group . ":";
$filestring = get_user_data($user, "groups");
$pos = strpos($filestring, $findme);
if ($pos === false) {
return "false";
} else {
return "true";
}
}
```

Just so you know, the "get_user_data() function will return a set of groups that the user belongs too. For instance, it will return 5:1;6:1;7:1 etc... The part that is important is the number before the colon and the colon itself, eg: 5:, but not 5:1. The one represents the priviledges the user has and is part of another coded page, so its not important here.

The "groups" string will return the group assigned to the forum. This code above works perfectly. If it returns true, the forum will be visible, otherwise it will return false.

However, I tried to make it so that it can have more than one group assigned to the forum and I used this code which does not work as intended:

```
function checkgroupstat($group, $user) {
$groups = explode(',', $group);
$filestring = get_user_data($user, "groups");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($groups); ++$i) {
$findme = $groups[$i] . ":";
$pos = strpos($filestring, $findme);
if ($pos === false) {
$false = "true";
}
else {
$truth = "true";
}
}
if ($truth == "true") {
return "true";
}
if ($truth == "") {

return "false";
}
}
```

I even tried using for each loop with break;

Any suggestions?

---

EDIT:

Suggestions below did not work. See my latest response which is:
The paramaters passed to checkgroupstat are: ("1,2,3", 6). The results returned from get_user_data() are 5:1;6:1;7:1;8:1;. Neither of these worked for me btw.

Comment: Please indent properly the source code.

Comment: Your code has another problem: it doesn't work correctly for 2-digit groups. If the user is in group 21, it will return true for group 1, because it just searches for `1:` in the string.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Perhaps I can add a space in the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying the following? ;)

```
function checkgroupstat($group, $user) {
    $groups = explode(',', $group);
    $filestring = get_user_data($user, "groups");

    // iterate over the group array 
    // return true if a group has matched
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($groups); $i++) {
        $findme = $groups[$i] . ":";
        $pos = strpos($filestring, $findme);
        if ($pos !== false) {
            return "true";
        }
    }

    // if no group has matched in the loop above
    // we'll have to return false
    return "false";
}
```

Comment: The code you provided. It seems it doesn't return true or false. So its not detecting if the user is in the proper usergroup.

Comment: try my update. I'm now returning strings -> "true" , "false". This seems what you expect in your example.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that already, but I copied your code anyway. Didn't work.

Comment: I tried it it with the arguments you posted in the comment on the other answer -> it returned "false" . as expected. Tried it with $groups = "1,2,6" and it returned "true". also as expected. Your problem must be in an other part of your code.

Comment: But I tested the other code and it seems to return the proper result. I tried using this on a test page using it outside of a function, but still using the rest of the sites code and it worked. But calling it in a function doesn't. Also, the original code I had did work. It was getting everything right. It just cant seem to return true or false properly.

Comment: I have tested the example in my answer and it worked as expected. Have you changed the code that calls `checkgroupstat()` so that it now passes a `;` separated list instead of just a group number? However, your example above should work too although being a bit to complicated should work too if I understand your question right. The problem must be in other part of code.

Comment: Is that edit still in this thread? If so, yes, I have tried it.

Comment: I just wanted to say that your code did finally work hek! It seemed that the problem was that the first entry in the user member-group search (EG: 5:1; 6:1, etc...) was ignored for some reason. Once I added a dummy entry in front of those digits in the database field (EG: 0:0; 5:1; 6:1; etc...) the code worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm.... please give me the checkgroupstat() passed parameters, and the get_user_data() return string. I will write correct code.

From now I just write this:

```
function checkgroupstat($group, $user) {
$aUserGroups = get_user_data($user, "groups");
$aGroups = explode(',',$aUserGroups);
foreach($aGroups as $sGroup) {
    list($iGroup,$iSomething) = explode(':',$sGroup);
    if($group==$iGroup) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

Please - give me feedback if it work fine :)

Comment: The paramaters passed to checkgroupstat are:   ("1,2,3", 6). The results returned from get_user_data() are 5:1;6:1;7:1;8:1;. Neither of these worked for me btw.

Comment: I added a var_dump code: echo "filestring: " . var_dump($filestring) . "<br>";
echo "group: " . var_dump($groups) . "<br>";
echo "user: " . var_dump($_SESSION['user_id']) . "<br>";                                         and this is what it returned: 
string(29) "5:1; 6:1; 2:1; 3:1; 4:1; 1:1;" filestring:
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } group:
string(1) "6" user: